# Angular 2 get service by string name

Tags: angular, angular2-di, angular2-injection

Is there a way get an instance of an injectable service of angular 2 just by the service name?

For Example, in Angular 1 you could write:

```
var service = $injector.get('ServiceName');
```

and the `service` variable would get an instance of the service.

I'd really appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you provide it by name, you can inject it by name

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
      ServiceName, 
      {provide: 'ServiceName', useExisting: ServiceName}
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: How would I go about getting this service from a component? Using `Injector.get` is deprecated as of version 4

Comment: "Injector.get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any is now deprecated use the same method which is now overloaded as Injector.get<T>(token: Type<T>|InjectionToken<T>, notFoundValue?: T): T;" https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta5-2017-01-25

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how would this be used in a component? I'm trying to upgrade the code from this answer to the 'new' format, but I can't wrap my head around the whole `InjectionToken` thing

Comment: `InjectionToken` is just a key used to register a provider with and then to request an instance for this key with `.get(...)`.

Comment: How would I get the key if it's passed as a string variable from a template? [Example of what I mean](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3admbe) (check out hello.component.ts)

Comment: I see what you mean. Should work as explained in https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183726/discussion-between-paradoxis-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question. I'm quite out of practice with Angular.

Comment: downvoting answer, as it's incomplete - does not show how to access such service, only how to define name for a service.

Comment: @MaciejMiklas that's shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Explicit injector creation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#explicit-injector) using the [Injector Class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Injector-class.html)

```
injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([ServiceClass, Dependency1Class, Dependency2Class]);

let service= injector.get(ServiceClass); //pass the type not the name
```

Comment: That wasn't what the OP asked.

Comment: It's another option! I haven't contribute with stackoverflow anymore because of this kind of behavior. Options should be given.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. The question clearly asks "just by the service name?", so offering a solution that just ignores that restriction is not helpful.